# Heroku + PaperClip + s3 credentials... One for every app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

Am I supposed to create a new security credential on Amazon S3 for every app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not it is required, I cannot say, but having separate security credentials for every application would be in line with the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege), reducing the permissions and authority each program or process to what is strictly required to do its job.